# How to make conversion from string to timestamp one-to-one?

Tags: php, time, timezone

I'm totally confused with PHP UTC/Local time conversions. Some functions convert time implicitly, some don't. Argh!!!

Say, I have this PHP code:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2016-05-13 09:26:30");  //From MySQL date format
//$timestamp returned is 1463153190
```

Then if I [convert](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) 1463153190 to UTC time, it becomes `05/13/2016 @ 3:26pm (UTC)`. Why???

How do I get a function to convert time from string to a timestamp *one-to-one*, without any time-zone shenanigans?

Comment: You can't, not without using timezones at all, unless the timezone is explicit in your time string in the first place; but consider using DateTime objects rather than date functions like strtotime(), because it makes timezones a whole lot easier to work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2016-05-13 09:26:30` is an incomplete timestamp, since it's missing the timezone. It could refer to over 24 different "absolute points in time", depending on which timezone it's being interpreted in. `1463153190` is an absolute UNIX timestamp for an absolute point in time. To convert your former timestamp to an absolute point in time, it needs to be interpreted as *some* timezone. The conversion the other way around also needs some timezone to format the point in time in.

In PHP the default timezone is considered when converting to or from UNIX timestamps. You can set that using [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set).

You see what you're seeing because `date_default_timezone` is set to some timezone (~+6) when converting from the human readable format to the UNIX timestamp, but then you're converting it back explicitly using UTC. Your initial timezone was simply not UTC/the timestamp was not initially interpreted as being in UTC. There's a timezone mismatch between the initial value and the final value, hence an offset of 6 hours.